# R: Initialize Vector skips fields

Tags: r, vector, initialization

I want to calculate and plot stochastical differential equations, based on odinary differential equations, using R. The values for each timestep of the ODE are calculated. Now based on them I want to calculate the values of the SDE and in this process I noticed, that the snippet is skipping some fields. Output of nres is below.

Could you explain me that behaviour?

Thank you

```
timestep <- 0.01
times <- seq(0, 25, timestep)
N <- length(times)
nres <- vector("list", N)

for(i in times){
   print(i)
   current <- i/timestep 
   if( current > 0 ) {
      nextPos <- current + 1
      nres[[nextPos]] <- 1
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[[25]] 1
[[26]] 1
[[27]] 1
[[28]] 1
[[29]] 1
[[30]] **NULL**
[[31]] 1
[[32]] 1
[[33]] 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to

```
current <- round(i/timestep)
```

Comment: With this solution you only have 1 `NULL` left, the first one.

Comment: Thank you, I thougt i / timestep should always be an integer because i = n * timestep.

Comment: @KoenV that's because OP is always skipping the first index, `nextPos <- current + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work for me, because the definition/initialization of nres is missing. Anyway, my assumption is that it doesn't work because you're calculating your indices with floats. That can mess up things. Maybe adding round(... , 0) would work...

```
timestep <- 0.01
times <- seq(0, 25, timestep)
N <- length(times)

for(i in times){
   print(i)
   current <- i/timestep 
   if( current > 0 ) {
      nextPos <- round(current + 1, 0)
      nres[[nextPos]] <- 1
   }
}
```

Or another way to do what you want to do is:

```
timestep <- 0.01
times <- seq(0, 25, timestep)

for(i in len(times)){
    print(times[i])
    nres[i+1] <- 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you, edit my question and add the initialization.